# Strapi: Trigger other component on react

Tags: reactjs, admin, ref, strapi

In Strapi i have Relation with link (select Country, auto load content for all City). I change file app/extensions/content-manager/admin/src/containers/EditView/index.js on Select Country change but cannot trigger Select City.

```
const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value, type } }) => {
let inputValue = value;

if (name === 'country' && value) {
  setcountryId((value.id)? value.id : value._id);
  setcountryChange(!countryChange);
  // change here
}})
```

But it not work, anyone work on this, can help? 
Many thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an error message?

Comment: this is not work, don't have any error. thank you

Comment: If the file path provided in your question is the one you set in your application it cannot work as it is the wrong one. You should look at the EditViewDataManagerProvider instead.